# How to show sort button on TableFixHeaders

Tags: android

[image: here on header I use button for sort data in table and dynamically I want to change up and down arrow.]

I am using **InqBarna's library** for showing data in table format. I am facing issue for sort button change (ascending and descending order) when clicked on sort button on table header. Please help.

Here code snippet.

```
    private View getHeader(int row, int column, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_table_header, parent, false);
    }
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(column % 2 == 0 ? R.color.header_dark_gray : R.color.header_light_gray);

    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(headers[column + 1]);
    imageButtons[column +1] = ((ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sortButton));
    imageButtons[column +1].setTag(headers[column + 1]);
    imageButtons[column +1].setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    return convertView;
}

View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ImageButton imageButton =(ImageButton)v.findViewWithTag(v.getTag());
        String header = v.getTag().toString();

        switch (header) {
         // logic for change image
           case Query.AQ_NO:
                if (AQ_NO_FLAG) {
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sort_asc);
                  }
                break;
         }
}
```

Comment: please add your code snippet

Comment: please help thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

It could help you.
This is a [wrapper for InqBarna's library](https://github.com/miguelbcr/TableFixHeaders-Wrapper).

This is a code snippet of how to achieve the sorting headers. Anyway you will have to see the [whole example](https://github.com/miguelbcr/TableFixHeaders-Wrapper/tree/master/samples-wrapper/src/main/java/com/miguelbcr/tablefixheaderssamples) to understand how it works.

Here you render the header view:

```
public class OriginalHeaderCellViewGroup extends FrameLayout
    implements
    TableFixHeaderAdapter.HeaderBinder<ItemSortable> {

private Context context;
public TextView textView;
public ImageView iv_order_asc, iv_order_desc;

public OriginalHeaderCellViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.text_sotable_view_group, this, true);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    iv_order_asc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_order_asc);
    iv_order_desc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_order_desc);
}

@Override
public void bindHeader(ItemSortable item, int column) {
    textView.setText(item.text.toUpperCase());
    drawOrderArrows(item.order);
}

private void drawOrderArrows(int order) {
    iv_order_desc.setImageResource(order == -1 ? R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_up_24dp : R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_up_24dp_disabled);
    iv_order_asc.setImageResource(order == 1 ? R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_24dp : R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_24dp_disabled);
}
```

and here you attach the listener to the table adapter and perform the sorting:

```
private void setListeners(final OriginalSortableTableFixHeaderAdapter adapter) {
    TableFixHeaderAdapter.ClickListener<ItemSortable, OriginalHeaderCellViewGroup> clickListenerHeader = new TableFixHeaderAdapter.ClickListener<ItemSortable, OriginalHeaderCellViewGroup>() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(ItemSortable item, OriginalHeaderCellViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int column) {
            updateOderIndicators(item, column, adapter);
            boolean orderAsc = item.order == 1;
            boolean orderSectionsAsc =firstHeader.orderSectionsAsc;
            applyOrder(orderAsc, orderSectionsAsc, column, adapter);
        }
    };

    adapter.setClickListenerHeader(clickListenerHeader);
}


private void updateOderIndicators(ItemSortable item, final int column, TableFixHeaderAdapter adapter) {
    final boolean orderAsc = item.order == 1;
    firstHeader.order = 0;
    for (ItemSortable itemAux : header) itemAux.order = 0;
    item.order = !orderAsc ? 1 : -1;
}

private void applyOrder(final boolean orderAsc, final boolean orderSectionsAsc, final int column, TableFixHeaderAdapter adapter) {
    Collections.sort(body, new Comparator<NexusWithImage>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(NexusWithImage nexus1, NexusWithImage nexus2) {
            if (nexus1.isSection() || nexus2.isSection()) return 1;
            else if (orderAsc)
                return nexus1.data[column + 1].compareToIgnoreCase(nexus2.data[column + 1]);
            else
                return nexus2.data[column + 1].compareToIgnoreCase(nexus1.data[column + 1]);
        }
    });

    adapter.setBody(body);
}
```

Hope it helps you.